moment of inertia of cylinder of variable density + uniform rod - Part b).
The density at a distance  $r$ from the axis of a circular cylinder, of mass $M$ and radius $ a $, is $ \frac{ \rho_{0}a}{r} $, where $ \rho_{0} $ is a constant.
a).  Prove by integration that the moment of inertia of the cylinder about its axis is $ \frac{Ma^2}{3} $.
b). Two such cylinders are joined by a uniform rod, of mass $ \frac{2M}{3} $ and circular cross section of radius $ \frac{a}{4} $, the axes of both the cylinder and the rod being coincident. Show that the moment of inertia of this system about its axis is $ 11 \frac{Ma^2}{16} $.
My attempts:
Throughout I've not factored in length of cylinders because $I$ is independent of length about the cylinder axis - as far as I understand it!
Part a). I found this ok.
Moment of inertia about axis, $I = \displaystyle\int r^2 dm$
Considering a volume element $dV$ a distance $r$ from the axis, $dV = 2 \pi r L dr$
where $L$ is the lenth of the cylinder. Taking $L=1$ unit, $\Rightarrow dV = 2 \pi r  dr$
Given the density at distance $r$ from the axis is, $ \rho(r) = \frac{ \rho_{0}a}{r} $
$\Rightarrow$ mass of element at distance $r$ from the axis, $ dm = \rho(r)dV$
$ \Rightarrow dm = 2 \pi r \frac{ \rho_{0}a}{r} dr$
$ \therefore dm = 2 \pi \rho_{0} a dr$
$ \therefore I = \displaystyle \int_0^{a} r^2 (2 \pi \rho_{0} a) dr $
After integrating, $ I = \frac{2}{3} \pi \rho_{0} a^4 $
Mass of cylinder, $ M =  \displaystyle\int _0^{a} dm = \displaystyle\int _0^{a} 2 \pi \rho_{0} a dr = 2 \pi \rho_{0} a^2 $
$ \frac{I}{M} = \frac{\frac{2}{3} \pi \rho_{0} a^4}{2 \pi \rho_{0} a^2} = \frac{a^2}{3} $
$ \therefore I = \frac{Ma^2}{3} $, as required.
Part b). I first thought of working out the mass both cylinders together with a hole bored of radius $\frac{a}{4}$ :
mass of both cylinders with hole bored = $ 2 \times \displaystyle\int _{\frac{a}{4}}^{a} dm = 2 \times 2 \pi \rho_{0} a \left [r \right]_{\frac{a}{4}}^{a} = 4 \pi \rho_{0} a \left(a - \frac{a}{4} \right) =  3 \pi \rho_{0}a^2 $
From (a), mass of one cylinder (without hole) is $ M = 2 \pi \rho_{0} a^2 $, $ \Rightarrow $  mass of bored out cylinders joined is, $M$, $= \frac{3M}{2} $.
The mass of the uniform rod is given as $ \frac{2M}{3} $, $ \Rightarrow $ mass of compound system $ = \frac{3M}{2} + \frac{2M}{3} = \frac{13M}{6} = \frac{13 \pi \rho_{0} a^2}{3} $
Moment of inertia of rod $ I_{r} $, by standard formula, $ I = \frac{mr^2}{2}$ with $ m = \frac{2M}{3} $ and $ r = \frac{a}{4} \Rightarrow I_{r} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{2M}{3} \right) \left(\frac{a}{4} \right)^2 $
$ \therefore I_{r} = \frac{Ma^2}{48} = \frac{ 2 \pi \rho_{0} a^4}{48} =  \frac{ \pi \rho_{0} a^4}{24}$
Moment of inertia of double cylinder with hole bored, $ I_{C} =  \displaystyle \int_{\frac{a}{4}}^{a}  (2 \pi \rho_{0} a) r^2 dr  $
$ \therefore  I_{C} =  (2 \pi \rho_{0} a) \left[ \frac{r^3}{3} \right]_{\frac{a}{4}}^{a} = \frac{2 \pi \rho_{0} a}{3} \left( a^3 - \frac{a^3}{64} \right)  =  \frac{2 \pi \rho_{0} a}{3}  \left( \frac{63a^3}{64} \right)  $
$ \therefore  I_{C} = \frac{63 \pi \rho_{0} a^4}{96}   $
$ \therefore $ moment of inertia of double cylinder-rod system about the common axis $ = \frac{63 \pi \rho_{0} a^4}{96} + \frac{ \pi \rho_{0} a^4}{24} = \frac {67 \pi \rho_{0} a^4}{96}   $
I've played about trying to get this answer in terms of $M$, but can't get the result, $ 11 \frac{Ma^2}{16} $. Any clear leads to where I'm going wrong would be massively appreciated!

The moment of inertia of the rod is $\frac{Ma^2}{48}$ and that of two cylinders combined is $\frac{Ma^2}{3}$. They are just stick together, first a cylinder, then a rod and then another cylinder. The summation of the moment of inertia of all the components account for the total moment of inertia of the system, which is: $\frac{Ma^2}{48}+\frac{Ma^2}{3}=\frac{11Ma^2}{16}$

Oh wow, thanks! I made it much more complicated because in part b) I treated the cylinders as though they must have been bored out to take the uniform rod, and so become treated as cylinders with a hole.

Ahh yes, I now have it in my mind that the rod connects both cylinders like dumbells? Not the way I was thinking with the 2 cylinders together with a rod going through. It would have helped more if there was a simple illustration given in the question.

Completely Agree with You. An illustration would be helpful.
